# Component array property call by reference in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, copy, angular8

I have a method in an angular component that pass component property array in method, but property value is not changing:

```
private districtModel : LocationModel[] = [];

valueChange(apiService : ApiService,control : FormControl,url,targetModel: LocationModel[]) {
control.valueChanges.subscribe(newValue=>{

  if(control.value === ""){
    console.log("empty");
    console.log(this.stateTemp);
    this.stateModel = this.stateTemp;
  }
  else{
    this.stateModel = this.filterValues(newValue,this.stateModel);
  }

  if(this.stateModel.length===1){
    console.log(this.stateModel[0].id);
    apiService.GetLocationById<LocationModel[]>(url,this.stateModel[0].id)
    .subscribe(data=> {
      targetModel = data;
        //console.log(this.districtModel);
    });
  }
});
}
```

**Function calling**

```
this.valueChange(apiService,this.societyForm.controls['State'] as 
FormControl,"https://localhost:44355/Location/GetDistrict?StateId=",this.districtModel);
```

I want to change the value that is `this.districtModel` inside function but it's not changing

Comment: Does your api service return something? Does console.log(this.districtModel); display anything?

Comment: must be work, I made a simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3zqdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
targetModel = data;
```

you assign data to the local variable `targetModel` which will not change `this.districtModel`. What you could do, is clear the original array and assign new values to it:

```
targetModel.splice(0, targetModel.length, ...data);
```

This removes `targetModel.length` items from the array beginning at `0` and adds all items from `data`.

Comment: I wanted to same function for multiple dropdown. so i did this. is any way that we can change value of this.districtModel by reference.

Comment: @manoj Have you tried the code that I posted? This will modify `districtModel`.

Comment: when i use code u have given it's giving error in data part

targetModel.splice(0, targetModel.length, data);

Argument of type 'LocationModel[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LocationModel'.
  Type 'LocationModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'LocationModel': id, namets(2345)

Even 
targetModel.splice(0, targetModel.length, data[0]);
Also not working

Comment: Thanks now it's working 
But what can u explain the statement u have posted please.
targetModel.splice(0, targetModel.length, ...data);
what does it mean ?

Comment: @manoj See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice  and  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

If your object `LocationModel` contains nested objects, you can **deep copy** your array with `lodash`, before passing it to the function:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

// ...

const clonedDistrictModel = _.cloneDeep(districtModel);
```

If you only need **shallow copy**, use the spread operator like that:

```
const clonedDistrictModel = { ...districtModel }
```

Take a look here if you want to know different types of copy: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/

Comment: I don't want to clone object but need to reflect changes as par function in current object. like i have private districtModel : LocationModel[] = []; property in component but districtModel should be changed in function valueChange

Answer (score 0):

You can deep copy object to another object the following code.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object))
```

Comment: i want to change this.districtModel property. this property is using inside my html. and i want same method implementation for multiple dropdown so i want to send this.districtModel as a reference.